# Changing instruction that was misidentified in IDA Pro

Tags: assembly, ida, 68000

I am trying to compare a source code to a disassembled version of a Sega Genesis (68000 processor) game. I ran the binary through IDA Pro to disassemble it, and when I was going through the code and comparing it to the source code, I noticed that IDA Pro's disassembler labeled some instructions improperly. Is there a way to manually correct it? As it is, I cannot compile the disassembled code, because an error regarding that instruction will come up.

IDA Pro identifies the code as the following:

[image: Code]

Here is the hex view:

[image: Hex]

The hex code is -
`01 3C 00 1E 4E 75`

The correct instructions should be:

```
btst d0, #%00011110
rts
```

Here is a description of the BTST instruction:
[image: BTST]
[image: BTST-2]

Additional Information:

Here is the function in the source code:

```
Findhittype ;look for type of swing (forhand or backhand)
;input d0 = launch dir
;ouput  beq forhand
;   bne backhand
    neg d0
    add facedir(a3),d0
    and #7,d0
    btst    #3,attribute(a3)
    beq .1
    btst    d0,#%11110000
    rts
.1
    btst    d0,#%00011110
    rts
```

Here is the function in IDA Pro:

```
; ======S U B R O U T I N E=====================================
ROM:0000C198 ; look for type of swing (forehand or backhand)
ROM:0000C198 ; input d0 = launch dir
ROM:0000C198
ROM:0000C198 Findhittype:      ; CODE XREF: passmode+1B4↑p
ROM:0000C198                   ;ROM:0000C210↓p
ROM:0000C198                 neg.w   d0
ROM:0000C19A                 add.w   $54(a3),d0      ; facedir
ROM:0000C19E                 andi.w  #7,d0
ROM:0000C1A2                 btst    #3,4(a3)     ; attribute bit 3
ROM:0000C1A8                 beq.w   loc_C1B2
ROM:0000C1AC                         d0
ROM:0000C1AE
ROM:0000C1B2
ROM:0000C1B2 loc_C1B2:        ; CODE XREF: Findhittype+10↑j
ROM:0000C1B2                         d0
ROM:0000C1B4                 ori.b   #$75,(a6)+ ; 'u'
ROM:0000C1B4 ; End of function Findhittype
```

Extended screenshot of function

[image: Screen]

Dropbox Link to IDB:

[Dropbox Link](https://www.dropbox.com/scl/fi/ns1irxxi8sf4n21qj52gl/nhl94.bin.idb?rlkey=usncs7ue7o00w5cu4x5qjm9ex&dl=0)

Comment: Have you tried pressing `C` on the code in question (or `U` to undefine first if needed)? Looks like it's not identified as code. Otherwise, does `Edit > Patch program > Assemble` do what you want?

Comment: Also make sure that Xref isn't incorrect (may just be a constant) which might confuse IDA.

Comment: It does seem to identify it as code. I can change it to data, then press C again, and it still ends up showing up like this. When I go to ```Edit > Patch program > Assemble```, I get a "Sorry, this assembler doesn't support the assembler". I create a .LST file and assemble it with a batch file from a toolkit for Genesis/Mega Drive games.

Comment: Oh, yes the Xref is correct. There's actually 2 examples of this problem in the same code block. I can post the whole code block if that helps.

Comment: The more you can post the better (include opcode bytes in your output and copy paste it). I don't know what else could be attempted to fix it then other than the processor implementation having a bug (unlikely) or needing a hint, but I don't know it that well.

Comment: Would manual instruction help? Under ```Edit > Other > Manual Instruction...``` . I have IDA Pro 7.7.

Comment: Probably, at least visually and possibly the decompiler, I've never tried it. It's just weird the processor doesn't recognize it by itself. Btw, for the listings in your question, it helps if you set "Options > General > Number of opcode bytes (non-graph)" to something that shows them all in the same line. PS: Is that really the end of the function or did IDA incorrectly recognize it? What follows it? Include some surroundings if possible.

Comment: Thanks, I added a screenshot showing the opcode bytes. Looking at the source code, it is the end of the function. You can see it's not identifying the RTS (4E 75) in both branches there. I can get it to identify the RTS if I change the code to data and then just convert the last part to code. The code following at C1B8 starts another function that IDA didn't recognize automatically.

Comment: Maybe it helps IDA to define a function at C1B8 (press `P` on it)?

Comment: No, unfortunately doesn't seem to make a difference.

Comment: Is it possible to share the IDB?

Comment: Thanks, I added a dropbox link to the IDB

Comment: My version of IDA is too old to open that IDB, so I sadly am out of ideas here. PS: reverseengineering.stackexchange.com is typically used for IDA questions nowadays, and you may even get help from the IDA authors there.

Comment: Thank you for your help!! I will go over there